# how to call tab bar view controller by click button function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have one `common tab bar view controller`.And i have connected `3 other view controllers` with `navigation bar` and i connect this 3 view controllers with the main `tab bar view controller`.So now i have 3 tab bar items with 3 view controller.

that is  `1.Home   2. Cart   3. feedback`

This is fine !!

And now my `first view controller`(That is my first `tab bar view controller`) have some `table view data` and with `detail view controller`.And in my `detail view controller` i have one button called "`Go to cart`".

So the actual flows is when user press `Go to cart`.It have to move to cart` view controller.Now its moving.

**But the problem is .I was not able to see my tab bar items and other items .But if i go normal to each tab bar items its showing all tab bar items.**

When i go from my Detail view button click to my `Cart` tab bar view controller..Then no tab bar items are showing down.

I did all this like demo prototype.Like i drag from button to cart tab bar view controller navigation bar.

But its not showing tab bar why.Please help me out.I don't have any single solution to solve this.I am using swift 2.2.

Thanks.

[image]

Updated :

So i need to code some thing like this Right?.But i don't know how to handle this code:

```
 let barViewControllers = sender.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController

    let nav = barViewControllers.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController

    let destinationViewController = nav.topViewController as! CartVC
```

But i am getting crash in first line :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Please help me out

Comment: How are you going from detail to cart?...add some code & images of storyboard...people might be able to help.Check this how to ask questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @sanman  Now please check my updated post.And thanks

Comment: Your add to cart segue is modally presenting the cart viewcontroller instead of changing tab on tabbar controller.That is why you are not able to see any tabbar at bottom.

Comment: @sanman now what should i have to do .To see the tab bar

Comment: ok.But if i call to tab bar view controller means.Its showing the first tab bar option view controller.Because my cart tab bar view controller is second option.So if i call to main tab bar view controller.My first option`Home Tab`.That `home tab bar view controller only showing` instead of my cart tab bar view controller

Comment: You can access your tabbar controller in "detailVC" using self.tabBarController.From tabbarcontroller access your "cart vc" to set value for its variables if you need to.Then change the selected index of tabbarcontroller using self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; Ask if you have any queries.

Comment: Please give me some code example.I am new to iOS dev.I din get you what you saying.BY  button click in detailVC.i NEED TO WRITE SOME CODE TO PASSS TO CART VC.but i don't how how to handle that.

Comment: @sanman now please see my update and please help me out.Thnaks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Here is storyboard similar to yours.

Now remove segue from button "go to cart" which is similar to "show second tab" button in my storyboard

Instead provide action to it as follows,

```
 @IBAction func showSecondTab(sender: AnyObject) {
            let  navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
            ///secondviewcontroller in your case is cart
            let secondViewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as! SecondViewController
            //set values you want to pass
            //lets say I want to pass name to secondVC
            secondViewController.name = "ABCD"

            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    }
```

you can print and check values in viewDidLoad of secondVC(CartVC).